# importing database using xamp error for table that have multi foreign key

Tags: mysql, xampp

> Error in foreign key constraint of table
>   `blood_bank`.`blood_contact`:
>
> Create  table `blood_bank`.`blood_contact` with foreign key constraint
>   failed. Referenced table `blood_bank`.`contact` not found in the data
>   dictionary near ' FOREIGN KEY (`contact_fk`) REFERENCES `contact`
>   (`contact_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,   FOREIGN KEY (`blood_fk`)
>   REFERENCES `blood_group` (`blood_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE )

Here's the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `blood_contact` (
  `blood_contact_id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact_fk` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `blood_fk` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`blood_contact_id`),
  KEY `contact_fk` (`contact_fk`),
  KEY `blood_fk` (`blood_fk`),
  CONSTRAINT `blood_contact_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_fk`) REFERENCES `contact` (`contact_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`blood_fk`) REFERENCES `blood_group` (`blood_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Are you importing the structure into an empty database?

Comment: not broh i have the file how can show you

Comment: If it's not a very large file, you may edit your question to include the data in it. Just copy-paste the contents in the edit. If it's too large, remove all insert commands and keep only table structures with constraint statements.

Comment: now i edit and post the table query

Comment: Is this the only table you have, or do you have more tables? Before this create table command is run, you need to have the blood_group table. Seems like you don't have the full back up to import. If this is the case, and you still want to import the data, simply remove the line that mentions FOREIGN KEY.